# Error running mult.icc for multiple ICC's from a dataset

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to run `mult.icc` to calculate multiple ICC's from a dataset. Data has group ID column, and 9 variables. All variables a numeric. I have run the following:

```
mult.icc(data[,c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9")],grpid=data$GroupID)
```

Sourced from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/multilevel/versions/2.6/topics/mult.icc

And received error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~DV + grpid, data = <environment>,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'DV'
```

I have attached sample data.

[image: sample data]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's `mult.icc` and how is it related to ICC? Did you read the [tag:icc] tag description? It's for Intel's Compiler. Please remove that and tag the language and every related thing properly

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. We can't run your code on a picture of a table of data, but would need some workable sample of the data itself